# Cannot mount volume in docker container when directory name contains colon

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I cannot mount a volume to a docker container when the directory name contains a colon (:)

The name of the directory is 2012-08-05-00:16:37 and I prefer not renaming the directory. I tried:

```
docker run -it --name test1 \
-v /host_system_path/2012-08-05-00\:16\:37/:/container_path/2012-08-05-00\:16\:37/ 
image_name
```

I get the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec.See 
'docker run --help'.
```

If I rename the directory without spaces or only with hyphens, then the directory is mounted into the container without any issues. Can someone point out how can I solve the problem when the directory contains a colon.

I am on Ubuntu:16.04 and Docker version 17.06.0-ce.

Answer (score 2):

Colons are currently not supported when specifying directory mappings via `-v`, and it seems you cannot escape them either.

You need to leverage `--mount` [instead](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604#issuecomment-332673783):

```
docker run ... --mount type=bind,source=/some:colon:file,destination=/container-path ...
```

In the worst of cases, you may of course alternatively still work around this limitation with a temporary system link (`ln -s`) or rename the target directory temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [open issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8604) with Docker. But in your case, why would `docker run -it --name test1 -v /host_system_path:/container_path image_name` not be sufficient?

Comment: In general docker run -it --name test1 -v /host_system_path:/container_path image_name works except when the name of the host directory has colons. The directories are astronomy data and colons are used in all of them for easy categorization. Therefore, renaming it is not an option because I am dealing with several similar directories.  It is is also not possible to rename after mounting the data into the container.

Comment: Yes, I get that; I'm saying just mount the parent directory containing the directory with colons in the name. You are giving it the same name anyway, so just skip over the bits with a colon and mount the parent.

Comment: In the meantime the issue has been closed, though not fixed (`--mount` works with colons in the host path, but not in the container path).